# Why can't I create an array of an object I created?

Tags: c#, winforms

The objective is to create a spreadsheet kind of program such as Microsoft Excel. I have created a cell class which I want to create multiple instances of. Is the syntax incorrect or am I missing something logically?

What I did so far:
- Create a cell class.
- Initialized array, only to get an error.

```
public partial class form_welcomeScreen : Form
{
    Label[] cellLetters = new Label[26];
    Label[] cellNumbers = new Label[26];
    Cell cell[] = new Cell[26]; 
    char cellLetter = 'A';
    int cellNumber = 1;

    public form_welcomeScreen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Btn_newSheet_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++)
        {
            Cell cell = new Cell();
            pnl_main.Controls.Add(cell.createCell());
            cell.CellLetter = cellLetter;
            cell.CellNumber = cellNumber;
            cellLetter++;
            cellNumber++;
        }
    }
}


class Cell : System.Windows.Forms.TextBox
{

    private char cellLetter;
    private int cellNumber;
    private string cellID;

    public char CellLetter
    {
        get { return cellLetter; }
        set { cellLetter = value; }
    }

    public int CellNumber
    {
        get { return cellNumber; }
        set { cellNumber = value; }
    }

    public string CellID
    {
        get { return cellID; }
        set { cellID = CellLetter + Convert.ToString(CellNumber); }
    }

    public TextBox createCell()
    {
        TextBox cell = new TextBox();
        cell.AcceptsReturn = true;
        cell.Name = cellID;
        cell.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 25);
        return cell;
    }
```

I expect an array to be created so I can be able to create a whole spreadsheet of cells rather than just the one.

Comment: I think that the problem is that You draw the Cells one on top of another that is why you think that you only draw one.

Comment: You have to set the "cell.Location" for each cell to draw it in the correct place

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line:

```
Cell cell[] = new Cell[26];
```

gives you mismatched types (`cell` vs `cell[]`).  It should be:

```
Cell[] cell = new Cell[26];
```

Comment: Thanks. A rookie mistake that. Cheers for the quick help!

Comment: No problem!  Sometimes you just need a second set of eyes!

Comment: Feel free to mark this as the answer (and upvote, if you want) to let others know that this is the answer.  Cheers!

Comment: I believe it is set as the answer and I did upvote, however, it won't show since upvotes by users who have less than 15 rep points won't show.

Comment: No problem.  If the check mark is green, you've selected it as the answer.